# Mirror function for Binary tree in Java

Tags: java, binary-tree

QUESTION : Design a mirror method that computes the mirror image of a binary
tree.

What is wrong with my code?? This makes sense to me, however the only example that passes is my Leaf only example:

```
abstract class ABT {

    public abstract ABT mirror(); 
    }

class Leaf extends ABT { 
    int val; 
    Leaf(int val){ 
        this.val = val; 
    }

public ABT mirror() { 
    return this; 
}
}

class Node extends ABT { 
    int data; 
    ABT left; 
    ABT right; 
    Node(int data, ABT left, ABT right) { 
        this.data = data; 
        this.left = left; 
        this.right = right; 
    }

public ABT mirror() { 
    return new Node(this.data, this.right.mirror(), this.left.mirror());

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How is it not passing?
I added some test methods and it seems to work

```
public class TreeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TreeTest();
    }

    TreeTest(){
        Leaf one = new Leaf(1);
        Leaf two = new Leaf(2);
        Leaf three = new Leaf(3);
        Node node23 = new Node(23,two,three);
        Node root = new Node(0,one,node23);



        System.out.println(one+"<->"+one.mirror());
        System.out.println(root+"<->"+root.mirror());
    }

    abstract class ABT {

        public abstract ABT mirror();
    }

    class Leaf extends ABT {

        int val;

        Leaf(int val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

        public ABT mirror() {
            return this;
        }
        public String toString(){
            return Integer.toString(val);
        }
    }

    class Node extends ABT {

        int data;
        ABT left;
        ABT right;

        Node(int data, ABT left, ABT right) {
            this.data = data;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        public String toString(){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(data).append(",{").append(left.toString()).append("},{")
                    .append(right.toString()).append("}");
            return sb.toString();

        }
        public ABT mirror() {
            return new Node(this.data, this.right.mirror(), this.left.mirror());

        }
    }
}
```

And the output is:

1<->1

0,{1},{23,{2},{3}}<->0,{23,{3},{2}},{1}

Isn't it mirrored?

Comment: My following tests do not pass: (new Node ( 1, (new Node (2, new Leaf (3), new Leaf (4)), new Leaf(6))) does not result in ( new Node (1, new Leaf (6), new Node (2, new Leaf(4), new Leaf(3)))

Comment: How do you test it? Can you show me the string representation? Do you use equals() method?

Comment: Just tried your test case. The toString() gives identical Strings, so it works.